# Need guidance on how to write this as a multi-threaded app

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have an app that i'm working on and here's what it currently looks like.
I was wondering if i could get some help making this a bit more efficient.
Was looking to make use of Task Parallel Library as well (that is if it would help).
There are no restrictions on how things are designed right now, meaning I can completely re-design any part of the app.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<ISystem> systems = GetSystems();
        if (systems.Where(s => s.Import = true).Count() == 0)
            return;

        var export = new Export();
        // Import & Export People
        exportData.LoadPeople();
        foreach(var system in systems)
            foreach(var person in export.People)
                system.Push(person);

        export.LoadLocations();

        foreach(var system in systems)
            foreach(var location in export.Locations)
                system.Push(location);

        export.LoadOtherData();

        foreach(var system in systems)
            system = system as IDifferentSystem;
            if (system == null) continue;
            foreach(var data in export.OtherData)
                system.Push(data);

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you mean by "efficient", and what problems you are trying to solve vs. the cost of maintaining a multi-threaded design.

For some extremely general advice, there are three types of problems where a multi-threaded design is appropriate:

1. You don't want a long-running task to block the calling thread.  This is perhaps more applicable to GUI applications where you don't want to block the main GUI thread, so the app can stay responsive.
2. The algorithm is the so-called "embarrassingly parallel", which means you can subdivide the data and run the algorithm in parallel across multiple cores.
3. Communication with other processes, local or remote.  Other processes are of course other threads.

The above is a bit over-simplified, but the point is, make sure you are solving the right problem as opposed to forcing your problem into a preconceived solution.  Lots of factors to consider when deciding to use a multi-threaded design.  Automated testing will become more difficult.  Will your design be maintainable with correctness of execution (no crash/hang/data corruption) and with your definition of performance for a particular app?  Sure the TPL makes a multi-thread design easier, but it definitely doesn't remove these costs altogether.

Always consider the alternatives.  For example #1 above can also be done using something asynchronous, perhaps an I/O callback gets run on your calling thread later on (even though this is internally multi-threaded, but you don't need to care about that).  This is still a single-threaded design, no locks to worry about.  Also for #2, it may be possible to use a more efficient algorithm and/or data structure layout to achieve performance.